# Maven project log4j not working

Tags: java, maven, log4j

I have a simple maven project and trying to get log4j implemented.

deploying to local tomcat.  Nothing printing in console of eclipse where I have logger.debug().

Am I missing something?

This is my structure:[image]

pom.xml:

```
<!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
<dependency>
<groupId>log4j</groupId>
<artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
<version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

Class:

```
final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(myclass.class);
```

.properties file

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, stdout
# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p     %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Comment: Why do you have several rootLogger properties defined? My guess is that the last one, which sets the rootLogger to ERROR level, is overriding the previous two settings. You should only have the DEBUG line in the middle.

Comment: what if I wanted those as well?

Comment: See my answer for an explanation

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove the superfluous rootLogger declarations:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout
# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p     %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Logging levels are inclusive of those levels "above" them. For example, setting the logging level to DEBUG will include DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, and FATAL messages automatically. There is no need to declare logging levels for each one.